# Duplicating linear layout and its content that I've created in layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to duplicate this Linear Layout that I've created in XML in Java?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Principal"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/principal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:entries="@array/Principal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Item"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:entries="@array/Product" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Quantity"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/qty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:entries="@array/Quantity" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Item Code"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Remarks per order"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rmrksPO"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the linear layout with objects that I want to duplicate to be below the existing layout when the TextView below is clicked.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/divider2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider2"
        android:text="@string/Add_NEw"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[This is the my layout, when I click the add new item I want to duplicate this layout and display it below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtFZv.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'duplicate'? Do you mean you want to change the UI from the first `LinearLayout` to the second?

Comment: I uploaded an Image of my layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate your layout:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View yourLayout = inflater.inflate(yourLayoutId, yourParent, false);
```

"yourLayout" will be a instance of your layout in xml.

Comment: Hi sir, i don't where i can put it. And what will I place in 'yourLayoutId'?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add Linear Layout Run time to Parent Layout, On the click of Textview
public class DuplicateLayout extends Activity {

    TextView addNew;
    LinearLayout ll3,LinearLayoutMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_duplicate_layout);
        LinearLayoutMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutMain);
        ll3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll3);
        addNew = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addNew);
        addNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(DuplicateLayout.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_duplicate_layout, null);
                LinearLayoutMain.addView(child, 1);
            }
        });

    }
}
//activity_duplicate_layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMain"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addNew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider2"
            android:text="Add_NEw"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```